# Rails - Active Record Query Not Querying on Variable Assignment (Want to Load Eagerly)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

This is a query that returns all question submissions that have rubric_item_evaluations with present=true and has a rubric item with @rubric_item.id

```
submissions_to_update = QuestionSubmission.joins(:rubric_item_evaluations).where(:rubric_item_evaluations => {:present => true , :rubric_item_id => @rubric_item.id})
```

Then we destroy rubric item

```
@rubric_item.destroy
```

Then we iterate through the submissions to regrade

```
submissions_to_update.each do |submission|
  submission.grade!
end
```

But for some reason question_submissions_update gets queried afterwards on the .each! And by that time it doesn't query the right thing (returning an empty array). I'm confused... Why doesn't it query on initial variable assignment?

So in summary query seems to happen here

```
submissions_to_update = QuestionSubmission.joins(:rubric_item_evaluations).where(:rubric_item_evaluations => {:present => true , :rubric_item_id => @rubric_item.id})
@rubric_item.destroy
# Query for submissions_to_update happening after I destroy the rubric item
submissions_to_update.each do |submission|
  submission.grade!
end
```

I can show the SQL statements if necessary!

**UPDATE**
It is necessary that I actual execute the query before destroying the rubric item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is to call `.load` on the query.

```
QuestionSubmission.joins(:rubric_item_evaluations).where(:rubric_item_evaluations `=> {:present => true , :rubric_item_id => @rubric_item.id}).load
```

**Collection proxies are lazy evaluated and only run sql queries when it needs to.**

So in order to actually execute the query on the variable assignment (e.g. eagerly), simply call `.load`.

More info on the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/load

Answer (score 2):

When you write this:

```
submissions_to_update = QuestionSubmission.joins(:rubric_item_evaluations).where(:rubric_item_evaluations `=> {:present => true , :rubric_item_id => @rubric_item.id})
```

You are building an ActiveRecord::Relation, this is the query itself in active record format but in the end you are just building a query not executing it.

Then you just said right after building the query you destroy @rubric_item, so the query built previously will become wrong afterwards. @rubric_item.id is not anymore in the database so the join query will not find any record.

You need to retrieve questions before destroying the item so in fact you need to execute your regrading process before destroying rubric_item such as:

```
submissions_to_update = QuestionSubmission.joins(:rubric_item_evaluations).where(:rubric_item_evaluations => {:present => true , :rubric_item_id => @rubric_item.id})
submissions_to_update.each do |submission|
  submission.grade!
end
@rubric_item.destroy
```

Comment: Indeed I thought that was happening. But the thing is, I actually need to call the query before `@rubric_item.destroy`. This has to do with the `grade!` method which I haven't posted. Is there a way to query on the initial variable assignment?

Comment: It could possibly load many rows. It's a heavy query. I mean of course I could just put the `@rubric_item.destroy` in the each loop that doesn't seem the best way.

Is there no rails way of having the query return the collectionProxy on the variable assignment?

Comment: Ah I figured it out. It's `.load`. It's interesting it took me so long to find this out. Seemed like it would be a prevalent occurence.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I added my findings below.